# Python Multiplayer Games

Tags: python, networking, pygame, multiplayer

I have been trying to find a good tutorial for making multiplayer games with python, but have struggled to find one that covers more than multiplayer on the same wifi connection.

If  its even possible, and you guys now one, or even how to do it, (module, library..), could you please share with me?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked out pygame fully?  I notice that you include it in your tags....

Comment: Yes,  I have done a few games in pygame and  I am pretty familiar with it, and that is why I want to take in to the next level, doing multiplayer games.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible. You might try [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), a popular event-driven networking engine written in Python.

Also check out [this page](http://pygame.org/tags/multiplayer) for examples of games written in PyGame that have multiplayer functionality (source code included)

Comment: I downloaded Twisted and tried to run one of their sample codes:

`from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
from sys import stdout

class Echo(Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        stdout.write(data)
`
 but it gave me this error:
`ImportError: No module named twisted.internet.protocol`

Comment: @user3530572 I can't see the proper format of your code inside the comment. Either make a new question about Twisted or edit your original question so we can help you with this problem.